# Why can I not draw the text on a button after turning the smarphone and using a CountDownTimer?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

Try to implement a CountDownTimer which should be displayed on a button. It works fine as long as I do not turn the smartphon. After turning the smartphone the button only shows the initial value text even though the cowndowntimer is still running. Does somebody know why the myButton.setText() method do not work in the onTick() method after turning the smartphone?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;
    private TextView myTextView;
    private Button myButton;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        myTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        myButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        myTextView.setText("Set new text");
        myButton.setText("Set Button text");
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myButton.setText("Button clicked");
                countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * 1000, 1000) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
       //After turning the Smartphone the follow both methods do not work anymore
                        myButton.setText( "Calc: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        myTextView.setText("Calc: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                    }
                };
                //timer started
                countDownTimer.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, check if the onFinish is called when you turned the device.

Comment: On Finish is not called after turning the Smartphone. I can also attache the Debugger and see that the timer is stil running after turning. But the myButton.setText( "Calc: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 method does not display the value.

Comment: In general I don't think you will be happy with this code. For example: have you seen what happens when you tap the button a second or third time lets say 5 secs after the initial tap?

Comment: If this is a special case app - one that only has this single purpose and you do not need to have the app react to rotation. Then your solution will work (just take care of the situation where the user can tap the button multiple times). You will need to restrict rotation by setting the activities `screenOrientation` in the Manifest. Otherwise, I **strongly** suggest you use a `Handler` and a background thread.

Comment: May be because you are changing the button text in onCreate() which will work fine until you don't minimize the app or lock your phone which will call onPause() and when you come back to your app it will call onResume()
 
 Try to change set the timer time on button text in onResume()

hope it works

Comment: I have worked the whole day on my problem, but i haven't found a solution. Does somebody haye any code examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code example...
Notice that I added the "DONE" text in the onFinish() method, so you can set the text for all UI Components you want... and also I added an if statement in the case that the app is running in the background in the case that you want to save some information before the app runs in the background

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myButton.setText("Button clicked");
            countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer( 3000, 1000) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //After turning the Smartphone the follow both methods do not work anymore
                    if (!runningBackground) {
                        myButton.setText("Calc: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        myTextView.setText("Calc: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    } else {
                        //Do something
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    if (!runningBackground) {
                        //Do something
                    }
                    mTextMessage.setText("DONE");
                    runningBackground = false;
                    running = false;
                }
            };
            //timer started
            countDownTimer.start();
            running = true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    runningBackground = false;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    runningBackground = true;
    super.onPause();
}
```